# XPath expression to pluck out attribute value

Tags: xpath

I have the following XML:

```
<envelope>
    <action>INSERT</action>
    <auditId>123</auditId>
    <payload class="vendor">
        <fizz buzz="3"/>
    </payload>
</envelope>
```

I am trying to write an XPath expression that will pluck out `vendor` (value for the `payload`'s `class` attribute) or whatever its value is.

My best attempts are:

```
/dataEnvelope/payload[@class="vendor"]@class
```

But this requires the expression to already know that `vendor` is the value of the attribute. But if the XML is:

```
<dataEnvelope>
    <action>INSERT</action>
    <auditId>123</auditId>
    <payload class="foobar">
        <fizz buzz="3"/>
    </payload>
</dataEnvelope>
```

Then I want the expression to pluck out the `foobar`. Any ideas where I'm going awry?

Comment: Which data you know initially? What you can use to identify required element? `action` value, `auditId`,... ?

Comment: Is the difference between the two XML examples intentional? If so, state that you need to be able to handle that difference when selecting the `@vendor` value. You can accommodate the difference in the XPath, if necessary. Otherwise, it would be less confusing for those answering if you didn't have `<envelope>` and `<dataEnvelope>` different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need `@class` value from `payload` node, you can use

```
/dataEnvelope/payload[@class]/@class
```

or just

```
/dataEnvelope/payload/@class
```

Answer (score 0):

At first, your two XML files are out-of-sync - one references `envelope` and the other references `dataEnvelope`. So exchange one for the other, if necessary.

So, to get the attribute value of `payload`, you can use an XPath expression like this which uses a child's attribute value to be more specific:

```
/envelope/payload[fizz[@buzz='3']]/@class
```

**Output is:**

```
vendor
```

Answer (score 0):

If the document element can/will change, then you can keep the XPath more generic and select the value of the `class` attribute from the `payload` element that is a child of any element:

```
/*/payload/@class
```

If you know that it will always be a child of `envelope`, then this would be more specific(but the above would still work):

```
/envelope/payload/@class
```